# Merging video chunks while streaming (on-the-fly)

Tags: bash, node.js, nginx, streaming, mp4

The setup:

- Video chunks of 200M
- An nginx server with the mp4 streaming module to serve the video

Is it possible to create a single mp4 file from the chunks, without interruptions to streaming them to the client?

I've tried manually to `cat file_chunk >> test.mp4` with a limited success. It works on one occasion (using vlc to play the file while doing `cat ...`), and doesn't work in different cases (streaming through a browser, using totem media player...).

Additionally, we are using Node.js for authentication and for the API in question (if that may somehow help).

The relevant nginx configuration:

```
 server {
        listen 441;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key; 
        root /video/;

        location *.mp4 {
            mp4;
            mp4_buffer_size 1m;
            mp4_max_buffer_size 5m;
        }
    }
```

Ideally, this could be somewhere in the lines of merging the chunks into a single file which is being streamed (without interruptions).

Comment: I don't know enough to be of any useful help, but would the `tee` command help?

Comment: The effect would be pretty much the same (I've tried it). Once the output file is changed, it usually confuses the software running the stream on the client side.

Comment: Even if you set the output file to be a fifo for example?

Comment: It turned out it wasn't an issue with file I/O, but with the streaming format itself. Basically, the point until it will stream is the size / length it receives on the initial request. Anything appended to the file afterwards is simply ignored. I'll be going for a (conceptually) different solution. Thank You!